# Very Basic Math question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

How can I prove that 
 $$\frac{r}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{rx}{x(1-x)} =  \frac{r}{x(1-x)^2}$$
I have tried to prove that , but I could not , can someone help me please  ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried multiplying both sides of the equation by $x(1-x)^2$?  Ordinarily, by multiplying both sides of the equation by an unknown, we need to be careful that we do not multiply both sides by something which can be zero, but technically when $x(1-x)^2=0$ the expression is undefined on both sides anyways, so we may ignore that issue.

Comment: This is not to offend you, but just asking ;in which grade are you studying?

Answer (score 2):

If your original expression to prove is actually: $$\frac{r}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{r}{x(1-x)} =  \frac{r}{x(1-x)^2}$$
then it works out as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac{r}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{r}{x(1-x)} &=\frac{rx}{x(1-x)^2} + \frac{r(1-x)}{x(1-x)^2}\\[1ex]
 &=\frac{rx +r -rx}{x(1-x)^2}\\[1ex]
&=  \frac{r}{x(1-x)^2}
\end{align}

As observed, though, your original expression doesn't generally work.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $x(1-x)^2$ (assuming $x\notin\{0,1\}$), we get

$$rx+rx(1-x) = r.$$

Or,
$$rx(1+1-x) = r.$$

Thus, unless $x(2-x) = 1$ or $r=0$, the above is not true.

So $x=1$ or $r=0$ are only two possible cases when equation may hold.

At $x=1$, LHS and RHS of original equation are unbounded, so only possible case is $r=0$.

Comment: $x(2-x)=1$ gives rise to the equation $x^2-2x+1=0$ which factors as $(x-1)^2$.  Note however, that the original expression has division by $(x-1)$ and so is undefined to begin with.

Comment: That depends on context.  Under ordinary contexts, you have the left and right expressions are both undefined, *not* infinity as infinity is not a number at all.  In the extended complex numbers you will indeed have $\infty=\infty$.  In the extended reals however it is unknown whether it would be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ on either side.  Approaching $1$ from the left and right give different values for one of the fractions, and $\infty-\infty$ is undefined.

Comment: agreed - the soln. reflects the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Take any reals $r,x$ such that $x \notin \{0,1\}$.

Then $\frac{r}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{rx}{x(1-x)^2}$.

And $\frac{rx}{x(1-x)} = \frac{rx(1-x)}{x(1-x)^2}$.

The sum of these is not $\frac{r}{x(1-x)^2}$.

However, the following is true:

> $\frac{r}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{r}{x(1-x)} =  \frac{r}{x(1-x)^2}$.